# how to add an object to a list in localstorage

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage

so basically i want to make a phone contacts app, and i try to save the saved contact to local storage

so this is the function when the save button clicked

```
saveContact(name, number){
        //To check if the name input or phone input is not blank
        if(nameInput.value == '' || phoneInput.value == ''){
            info.style.display = 'block'
        }

        const firstLetter = name[0].toUpperCase()
        const getContact = localStorage.getItem(firstLetter)
        const storedObject = {
            [name]:number
        }       

        //If contact's first letter exists in localstorage
        if (getContact){
            const oldData = [JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(firstLetter))]
            oldData.push([storedObject])
            const oldDataString = JSON.stringify(oldData)

            localStorage.setItem(firstLetter, oldDataString)

            const finalOldData = []


       //i do a looping here to push each contact's object to a new array which is finalOldData
      //but it doesn't work well. it doesn't actually add a new object to the array instead of replacing the old object with a new one
            oldData.forEach(e => {
                finalOldData.push(e[0])
                
            })
            const finalOldDataString = JSON.stringify(finalOldData)
            localStorage.setItem(firstLetter, finalOldDataString)
            
        }

        //If contact's first letter doesn't exist in localstorage
        else{
            const storedObjectString = JSON.stringify([storedObject])

            localStorage.setItem(firstLetter, storedObjectString)
            
            this.clearSave()
        }
        
    }
```

so the issue is when i try to add a contact which its first letter exist in local storage and make it as a list

//and this is the result i want

```
Storage
​
 A: "[{\"amber\":\"1242134\"},{\"annie\":\"123421\"}]"
​
length: 1
```

Comment: beacause i want to make each contact as an object, and put it inside an array which consist the others contact

Comment: Isn't `oldDataString` and `finalOldDataString` the same?

Comment: it's different. finalOldData is an array where i want it to be stored to local storage, where each item in it is an object. On the other hand oldData is an array which its item is an array. that's why i do a looping there and make it an object then push it to new array

Comment: Then why are you setting `localStorage.setItem(firstLetter, oldDataString)` firstItem to oldDataString?

Comment: Please check my answer below, consider updating your question to provide information on what do you exactly want to store in `localstorage`?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the code below, it is working as expected.

#### Changes

1. `const oldData = [JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(firstLetter))]`

No need to put the result from `JSON.parse` into an array, it already is an array and also you can use the variable `getContact` instead of calling `getItem` again on `localStorage`.

2. `oldData.push([storedObject])`

No need to push an array into `oldData`, simply push `storedObject`.

*I've removed the initial check for making testing easy, you can add it back.*

```
function saveContact(name, number) {
  if (!name || !number) {
    return;
  }

  const firstLetter = name[0].toUpperCase();
  const getContact = localStorage.getItem(firstLetter);
  const storedObject = { [name]: number };

  if (getContact) {
    const oldData = JSON.parse(getContact);
    oldData.push(storedObject);
    const oldDataString = JSON.stringify(oldData);
    localStorage.setItem(firstLetter, oldDataString);
  } else {
    const storedObjectString = JSON.stringify([storedObject]);
    localStorage.setItem(firstLetter, storedObjectString);
  }
}
```